# EF Core: Add records with decimal, non-identity PK

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an existing database with multiple tables with decimal (`numeric(14,0)`) PK columns. I'm experimenting with different ways to insert multiple records in one action.

I'm not sure if I can introduce sequences, so I've been trying to use `HasDefaultValueSql("MAX(CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) + 1")`. In a general use case, you could have 1-n CaseAttributes added at a time, so I don't necessarily to use EF to query for the next ID first.

I can probably add more detail, if necessary. However, what would typically be the best way to insert 1-n records with EF Core without the presence of an auto-incrementing identity column?

UDPATE:

Entity class except (I've tried both `None` and `Computed`):

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
[Table("CASE_ATTRIBUTE_CONFIG", Schema = "dbo")]
public partial class CaseAttribute : ISoftDelete, IUpdateTracker
{
    [Key]
    [Column("CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID", TypeName = "numeric(14, 0)"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public decimal CaseAttributeId { get; set; }
}
```

Context except:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CaseAttribute>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.CaseAttributeId).HasDefaultValueSql("MAX(CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) + 1").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    entity.HasQueryFilter(e => EF.Property<DateTime?>(e, "EffectiveEndDate") == null);
});
```

If I don't use ValueGeneratedOnAdd(), it just seems to insert '0'. Otherwise, I get the exception: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID', table 'RPE_V3_12_02_00.dbo.CASE_ATTRIBUTE_CONFIG'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.`

Using profiler, you can see it also generates some really strange SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID] numeric(14, 0), [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [dbo].[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_CONFIG] USING (
VALUES (@p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, @p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, 0)) AS i ([CASE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME], [CASE_ATTRIBUTE_REGEX], [CASE_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE], [CASE_SUB_TYPE], [CASE_TYPE], [CODE], [CODE_TYPE], [CORE], [DISPLAY_GROUP_NAME], [DISPLAY_ORDER], [DISPLAY_TAB], [EFFECTIVE_BEGIN_DT], [EFFECTIVE_END_DT], [IS_REQUIRED], [MAXIMUM_LENGTH], [NODE_NAME], [UPDATED_BY], [UPDATED_DATE], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([CASE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME], [CASE_ATTRIBUTE_REGEX], [CASE_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE], [CASE_SUB_TYPE], [CASE_TYPE], [CODE], [CODE_TYPE], [CORE], [DISPLAY_GROUP_NAME], [DISPLAY_ORDER], [DISPLAY_TAB], [EFFECTIVE_BEGIN_DT], [EFFECTIVE_END_DT], [IS_REQUIRED], [MAXIMUM_LENGTH], [NODE_NAME], [UPDATED_BY], [UPDATED_DATE])
VALUES (i.[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME], i.[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_REGEX], i.[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE], i.[CASE_SUB_TYPE], i.[CASE_TYPE], i.[CODE], i.[CODE_TYPE], i.[CORE], i.[DISPLAY_GROUP_NAME], i.[DISPLAY_ORDER], i.[DISPLAY_TAB], i.[EFFECTIVE_BEGIN_DT], i.[EFFECTIVE_END_DT], i.[IS_REQUIRED], i.[MAXIMUM_LENGTH], i.[NODE_NAME], i.[UPDATED_BY], i.[UPDATED_DATE])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [t].[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID] FROM [dbo].[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_CONFIG] t
INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID] = [i].[CASE_ATTRIBUTE_ID])
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];

',N'@p21 varchar(50),@p22 varchar(200),@p23 varchar(6),@p24 varchar(25),@p25 varchar(25),@p26 varchar(10),@p27 varchar(25),@p28 tinyint,@p29 varchar(100),@p30 decimal(1,0),@p31 varchar(25),@p32 datetime,@p33 datetime,@p34 bit,@p35 decimal(1,0),@p36 varchar(25),@p37 varchar(128),@p38 datetime',@p21='test-attribute',@p22=NULL,@p23='STR',@p24='ADMIN',@p25='MYTEST',@p26='MN',@p27='STATE_PROVINCE',@p28=4,@p29='display-group',@p30=1,@p31='',@p32='2020-10-01 00:00:00',@p33=NULL,@p34=0,@p35=4,@p36='node-name',@p37='admin@rsimail.com',@p38='2020-10-19 21:03:03.787'
```

Comment: When you tried to use the `HasDefaultValueSql()` statement above, what is the result you get? Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman See UPDATE above

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 2019, but that shouldn't matter. To me, this seems like an issue with how things are set up on the EF Core side (3.1)

Comment: @mschmidt73 Sure. I just wanted to confirm you were using a SQL Server version that has support for sequences, before suggesting you go that route

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if I can introduce sequences,

Is there any technical reason not to use [Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

You are configuring EF to generate the value on the server-side anyway. A Sequence would be much more efficient in generating the values (and EF doesn't need to know how it's generated), and has the added benefit that manual inserts you do via SQL Management Studio will also leverage the sequence.

You can add an empty EF migration (`dotnet ef migrations add ...`) that creates the Sequence and updates the table to use the next value of the sequence as the default value for the primary key.

Assuming the current `MAX(CaseAttributeId)` is `5000`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[CaseAttributeIdSequence] AS NUMERIC(14,0)
    START WITH 5001
    MINVALUE 5001
    INCREMENT BY 1
;
```

---

Update the table to use the next value of the sequence as the default value:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CaseAttribute]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_CaseAttribute_CaseAttributeId]
        DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[CaseAttributeIdSequence]
        FOR [CaseAttributeId]
;
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, this is probably the best way to go. Unfortunately, I don't have full control in this case and there's an existing pattern using a separate table rather than a sequence, which feels pretty gross. If one was to alter the table in this way (I'm assuming I can't introduce IDENTITY to a numeric column?), is EF smart enough to return the generated Id even though it's not an identity column?

Comment: If you alter the table to use a sequence and tell EF that the value is `DatabaseGenerated`, EF will bring the value back after you call `SaveChanges` so you'll end up with the desired result

Comment: Another option is to change the column in the SQL Server table to `INT` or `BIGINT` *and* IDENTITY, to get the normal behavior you want. You can decide between `INT` and `BIGINT` based on the `MAX(CaseAttributeId)` and expected growth... INT can hold up to `2147483647` and `BIGINT` up to `9223372036854775807`

Comment: Assuming I would have the authority to do that ... I thought I recalled that changing a column to IDENTITY was a big deal? Or is that removing IDENTITY once it already exists?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "big deal". It's just a few steps: Add the new `INT` or `BIGINT` column (e.g. `CaseAttributeIdentity`), copy the data to it, drop the old column (`CaseAttributeId`), rename the new column to `CaseAttributeId`, add the Identity & Primary Key constraint... If your table is massive, then yes maybe you consider it a big deal. Either way, I personally would prefer the sequence approach which is less risky to break anything and would give you the same result in the end.